# getSupportActionBar() NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

In `onCreate()` method of activity I have this code for `ToolBar`:

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

My IDE warms me that `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);` may produce ***`NullPointerException`***.

***My question is should I ignore it and how can I fix it anyway?***

Comment: Do you know what a NullPointerException is?

Comment: which toolbar are you using, are you using the support toolbar??

Comment: @VirajNalawade He is asking about a warning by Android Studio. It's not about an actual error.

Comment: IDE is just warning you dude :) IDE doesn't produce `nullPointerException`

Comment: @Bhargav support.v7.widget.Toolbar

Comment: findViewById(R.id.tool_bar) is null.Are you sure you have a Toolbar in layout?

Comment: @tinysunlight Lol, yes I do. And I see Home button and it works perfectly.

Comment: just alt + enter and ignore it .

Comment: @hata sorry my bad..!!

Comment: @tinysunlight thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The IDE warns you about a potential `NullPointerException` because there are many cases where the app could throw one. For the example you could be using a **NoActionBar** theme for your whole `Application` (or just for the concerned `activity`), but still you're trying to retrieve a reference to the action bar using `getActionBar()` (or `getSupportActionBar()`).

Just ignore the warning, but keep in mind the notes above.

**UPDATE:**

You can get rid of the warning by explicitly checking for nullability:

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
if (toolbar != null) {
    // you can safely invoke methods on the Toolbar
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
} else {
    // Toolbar is null, handle it
}
```

Comment: I am using **getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS , WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);** to get full screen length , I think that's the reason for me to get this nullPointerException . Is there any way to get out of this situation without removing above code.

Answer (score 2):

You could check for null but if it is not crashing it should not be nessessary:

```
if(getSupportActionBar() != null) {
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well both the answers are correct, but if you just want to remove the warning

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

assert actionBar != null;

actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

**assert actionBar != null**, says that ActionBar is not null, and so calling any method on this variable doesn't produce the warning of NullPointerException.

I guess it will work if you

```
assert getSupportActionBar() != null
```

But I'm not sure about that.

Answer (score 1):

If the **toolbar is in include layout**, we need to use the id of the include tag, instead of the toolbar tag.

```
<include  
android:id="@+id/toolbar_include"/>


<!--/**toolbar_include.xml*/-->

<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
android:id="@+id/toolbar"/>
```

That is use

```
 Toolbar toolbar=findViewById(R.id.toolbar_include);
```

Answer (score 0):

Above all answer given for escaping from NullPointerException,and after putting this in your code :-

```
if(getSupportActionBar() != null) {
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
```

Only solve exception issue after then also you will not get your toolbar null only.
I want to say just check in your activity xml u have declared your toolbar or not,i think this will reslove your issue.

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
```

***Just put toolbar in your activiy Xml.***